# Не корректно работает [].slice и последующая замена значений внутри нового массива

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с непонятным поведением кода. 
По идее должно получиться на alert: left+right  right+left, но 
выходит right+left right+left, что говорит о некорректности slice

```js
let paleta=[0,['left','right']];
let paleta_tmp= paleta.slice();//let paleta_tmp=[...paleta];    
let str1= paleta_tmp[1][0];
let str2= paleta_tmp[1][1];
paleta_tmp[1][0]=str2;
paleta_tmp[1][1]=str1;    
alert(paleta[1][0]+'+'+paleta[1][1]+' :  '+paleta_tmp[1][0]+'+'+paleta_tmp[1][1]  );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>OUT_test</title> 
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Какая у Вас задача?

Comment: `slice` работает корректно. Некорректно работает вот это `paleta_tmp[1][0]=str2;`

Comment: как раз это работает корректно, но происходит влияние на значения в переменной paleta чего быть не должно

Comment: slice - это slice, а не clone.

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю какие последствия понесёт за собой метка о дубликате вопроса, но мне кажется, что лучше его оставить, т.к. вопрос по поведению slice(), а не копированию объекта.

Comment: @XelaNimed, никаких последствий, кроме запрета на новые ответы.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно документации, [Array​.prototype​.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> ... возвращает новую "одноуровневую" копию

Другими словами, Вам нужно дополнительно скопировать массив на втором уровне:

```js
let paleta=[0,['left','right']];     
let paleta_tmp= paleta.slice();
// Здесь копируем подмассив     
paleta_tmp[1] = paleta[1].slice();
let str1= paleta_tmp[1][0];
let str2= paleta_tmp[1][1];
paleta_tmp[1][0]=str2;
paleta_tmp[1][1]=str1;    
console.log(paleta[1][0]+'+'+paleta[1][1]+' :  '+paleta_tmp[1][0]+'+'+paleta_tmp[1][1]  );
```

Comment: вот за этот ответ спасибо

Comment: @ignatyy, слева от ответа под кнопками для голосования галочка для принятия.